# PHP scripts seem to be executing twice

Tags: php, apache

I have a generic PHP maintenance script that sets a database value to prevent running at the same time as another instance. Usually run via cronjob.

I cleared the database value and tried running this script manually with the cronjob turned off. Every time I run it from the browser, it terminates immediately stating it is already running.

The script will run for about 30 seconds as a background process then terminate automatically as if PHP detected the browser was closed (should take about 15 min to complete).

So I added code to echo when the database value is set or read. It never echos when it's set, only when it was read, but I can see the database value is stored each time.

Script always finishes as expected if run from cron.

What could be going on? Could the server be executing scripts twice on each browser based request?

Server runs Hive so different dirs can have different PHP versions. Don't know if this could have something to do with it.

```
PHP 5.2.17 (default)
PHP 5.3.27 (dir this script is in)
Apache 2.2.25
```

Code that dictates if it runs is simply this:

```
$DB = new DbConnector($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);

if ($DB->queryOne("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_vars WHERE name = 'maintenance_running'")) {
    exit('Already running!');
} else {
    $DB->query("INSERT INTO data_vars (name, value) VALUES ('maintenance_running', 1)");
}
```

At the end of the script, the value is cleared. Again, this problem only happens when run from the browser.

Comment: Is it possible your browser is prefetching the page? In general, it's a bad idea for GET requests to have side effects.

Comment: Not sure how a prefetch could happen since a form on another page has to submit to execute this script when run from browser.

Comment: Check your server's access logs and see what hits come in on that script. If you get two hits, then the script is being run twice...

Comment: @MarcB Access logs show one entry each time I run it.

Comment: You say 30 seconds or so.. take a look at `set_time_limit()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php This could be affecting the requests coming from the user but not CLI as they might use different php.ini configurations. Most apache configurations automatically stop executing when the tab/browser is closed.

Comment: set_time_limit() is already employed in this script so it doesn't time out before it is done running.

Comment: @MarcB Just confirmed the script is in fact executing twice. Setup Xdebug's profiler and it spits out two profile logs. One for the full execution and one for the "already running" execution...both with only one submission of the form used to start the script. No idea what could be causing this.

Comment: Are you sure the DB connection and those queries are working ? Just wondering if the condition in the `if` is always returning non-false when running from the browser !

Comment: @EcomEvo, are you ever clearing the field. according to your code snippet, you will insert the row once (the first time). Afterwards every select count() will result in 1 and the else will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a longer value for execution limit with:

```
set_time_limit(30*60) // 30 minutes
```

Also the echo function probably is working, but as the response is sent to the browser until the whole script ends executing that is the cause that you can't see the print, because it´s killed by the execution limit before it ends and prints the response.

You can try echoing partially the response with the help of the

```
ob_start
```

and

```
ob_flush
```

You can read more about ob_functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)